# How to auto increment value in firebase realtime database using java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, auto-increment

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJA3s.png)

I need your help please, from this pict I have "Kode penj" which is it means order ID. If i click "Proses" button, data from first transaction will be send to firebase database and if i want to input another transaction, I want that order ID automatically change (+1) to "PJ200811002", etc. But i don't understand how to apply it.

**Fragment**

```
public class TransPenjFragment extends Fragment{
TextView kodetetap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trans_penj, container, false);
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    kodetetap = view.findViewById(R.id.kodetetap);
   

    SimpleDateFormat datepenj = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    final String transdate = datepenj.format(cal.getTime());
    kodetetap.setText("PJ" + transdate + "001");

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getActivity());
    firedb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = firedb.getReference();

    btnProses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isEmpty(kodetetap.getText().toString())){
                submitPenj(new PenjualanDB(kodetetap.getText().toString());

                String kode = kodetetap.getText().toString();

                int no=Integer.parseInt(kode);
                String cno=String.valueOf(no+1);

                for (int i = 001; i <= 999; i++) {
                    cno="001"+cno;
                    kodetetap.setText("PJ"+transdate+cno);
                }

                
            }

            else {
                Snackbar.make(btnProses, "Data penjualan tidak boleh kosong",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        autotgl.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
   } return view; }}
```

Anyone who know the answer, please tell me. Thank you so much.

Comment: you have to split the order id string after J. and then convert string into number and increment it and then again join with the pj to store in firebase

Comment: can you explain me in detail? Thak you so much